# Text color changes when removing position or z-index attribute

Tags: html, css

The bullet points in my unordered list below appear gray, but I want them to be white.

```css
* {
  z-index: 1;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#product {
  height: 35em;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
#product ul {
  padding: 0;
}
#product ul li {
  height: 35em;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
#product p {
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 15;
}
#product h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#pos {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
#ovrl {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  height: 35em;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="product">
  <div id="pos">
    <h1>Why Choose Us</h1>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>Customized
        <br>Software</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Workshop</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Digital
        <br>Advertising</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>E-learning</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="ovrl"></div>
</div>
```

When I remove `position: relative` from the `#product ul li` selector, then text is fully white but when it's present in the code text is not white.

And another problem when I ONLY remove `z-index: 1` from the `*` selector, then also it works fine.

But I cannot understand why. I need help please anyone solve my problem.

Comment: hello, welcome to stack overflow. i recommend that you try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. if you take the time to remove irrelevant details from your question, you are more likely to get a helpful answer -- and, in the process of re-writing your question, you are very likely to discover the answer on your own.

Comment: at a glance, i will say that when you set everything to the same z-index (which is what your `*` selector is doing), then they stack in the order they are rendered -- which means that the text really is white, but the semi-transparent black `#ovrl` div is on top of the text (making it appear gray).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a typo in #product ul li, try this:

```
#product ul li {
    position: relative;
}
```

Also, instead of using *, if you want something to be applied to the whole DOM, use the html tag

```
html {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Hope that helps! 
For the future, try to avoid using Ids on CSS, it's generally considered good practice to use classes on CSS and Ids on Javascript.

Comment: can u please tell me what is the typo i found ur code and my code the same,

Comment: It was on a previous version of your code, dw about it